# libpcap not linking netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans

I have been trying to learn libpcap on my mac. I am using netbeans IDE. I downloaded libpcap from tcpdump.org and tried to run a sample application from http://yuba.stanford.edu/~casado/pcap/section1.html.

I get these errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_pcap_lookupdev", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_pcap_lookupnet", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
```

I tried to manually link `libpcap` to netbeans by right clicking on *project-name->properties* and adding the libpcap folder to `Build->C++ compiler->Include Directories`. Pretty stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the *include* directories (= headers) you have to add the **library** too!

At **`Build -> Linker`** settings, add libpcap to **`Libraries`**; if not found - eg. you haven't placed it in default directories, add the path at **`Additional Library Directories`**.